# iOS 7.1 simulator: object cannot be nil

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator, addsubview

On the real device iPad with iOS 5.1.1 this code runs normally:

```
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
```

But in Xcode 6.4 iPad simulator iOS 7.1 crashes

```
NSLog(@"AppDelegate application 2");
NSLog(@"window: %@", window); 
NSLog(@"navigationController: %@", navigationController);
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
NSLog(@"AppDelegate application 3");


2015-09-12 14:24:35.251 SWPi[1209:607] AppDelegate application 2
2015-09-12 14:24:35.270 SWPi[1209:607] window: <UIWindow: 0x79fcdd80; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x79fd3860>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x79f721e0>>
2015-09-12 14:24:35.271 SWPi[1209:607] navigationController: <UINavigationController: 0x79fc8030>
2015-09-12 14:24:35.273 SWPi[1209:607] CRASH: *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
```

What happens?

Answer (score -1):

No matter will it solve the crash or not, I recommend adding `navigationController` to the VC hierarchy. In the most simple case you need just to change this:

```
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
```

to this:

```
window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question and is better off as a comment.